# Unable to synchronize Tomboy notes

Tags: ubuntu-one, tomboy

I keep getting a "Failed To Synchronize" message on my Tomboy notes (with nothing in the 'details' section).

It has been working for months, just stopped working a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be suffering from [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/709378) bug or [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/575937) bug.